How can I 3D visualize a GPS SEM Almanac, preferably in Python?
I'm able to download GPS SEM Almanacs from Celestrak, but would like to be able to visualize them in 3D with the Earth in the center.  How do I go about doing this?  Can this be done in Python with Orkit for example?

Welcome to Space SE! If you added a link to where you "download GPS SEM Almanacs from Celestrak" then more people could have a look and give it some thought. Thanks! Also, what "Orkit" do you mean? I don't see a Python package with that name https://pypi.org/search/?q=orkit

You might look an Manim, it can graph a set of points in 3D.  https://github.com/ManimCommunity/manim/

@uhoh I think the OP means Orekit (https://www.orekit.org/), which is written in Java, but does have a Python wrapper at https://gitlab.orekit.org/orekit-labs/python-wrapper/-/wikis/home

Thanks for the welcome, yes, the System Effectiveness Model (SEM) can be downloaded here:  https://celestrak.org/GPS/almanac/SEM/ and I misspelled Orkit, it's Orekit:  https://www.orekit.org/

defined as shown on p31 of this document https://www.gps.gov/technical/icwg/ICD-GPS-240D.pdf
